# Code-insight lags when i add MMsystem unit to uses clauses

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, code-completion

I am using Delphi Tokyo
I get a 5 second lag in `code-insight` when I add `MMsystem` to my `Uses` clause!.
It was a while that my program started having this huge delay on `code-insight`, so I looked for ways to optimize the `code-insight` on the internet but I was unsuccessful.
In the end, I created a new `FMX` project and simply added all the `Uses` from my previous project to this new project, and then I tested the `code-insight`, and I saw the delay! that was when I knew a certain `Unit` is causing this problem, so I started eliminating these `Units` one by one while testing Codeinsight after each elimination until I reached `MMsystem` and I noticed that this Unit is causing the problem!
**Now the question is:**
1- Why does this happen?
2- How can I fix this?
3- Is there an alternative to this Unit?
**Steps to reproducing this problem:**
1- Create a new `FMX project`(I am using Delphi 10.2)
2- Add `MMsystem` to `Uses`
3- go to an empty procedure like `Form Create` and press `Ctrl + Space`, each time you press these keys, it will take 4-5 seconds for the `code-insight` to show up

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - probably something else that interferes on your installation. FWIW my installation is on a SSD - you can see that IO from bds.exe goes up for a moment when you invoke code insight.

Comment: Stefan Glienke, my installation is on SSD as well, but is it not strange that only this particular `Unit` is causing this problem? how do you suggest I fix this?

Comment: For now, I was able to fix this temporarily by adding this unit's path directly inside the  `project.dpr` file, but I still don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Submit a bug report, we can't help you

Comment: If adding this unit iside project.dpr solved the problem then I don't think the problem lies in Code-insight but in your system instead. If I were you I would check the system PATH enviroment to make sure it isn't too long which could lead to all sorts of opther problems aswell. Also you might want to use program named Process Monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see steps being taken when Code-insight is trying to search for your MMsystem pas file to make sure that the cause of delays is not being caused by file system.

Comment: @SilverWarior very well, I will try to use the monitoring tool to find the problem, thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Hourglass showed for a split second and then presented with the drop-down. Also on an SSD, and quite a powerful machine though.

Comment: Interesting observation: adding `winapi` prefix will fix the problem!, meaning instead of using `MMSystem`, I must use `winapi.MMSystem`!